# Float iteration needed for calculation from .csv file

Tags: python, iteration, standard-deviation

I am looking to calculate the standard deviation for each column of a .csv file I have. Everything works up to this point but I keep getting the "TypeError: 'float object is not iterable" message. However, I need two of these values to be floats in order to retain the decimal places for accuracy. Is there a way to do this calculation with floats and not using iteration? Or is there an exception in the rule where I am able to use floats?

Here is the needed part of my code:

```
import math

fileChoice = input("Enter the file name: ") 
inputFile = open(fileChoice)

headers = inputFile.readline().strip().split(',')

dataColumns = []
for i in headers:
    dataColumns.append([])

rowCount = 0
for row in inputFile:
    rowCount = rowCount + 1
    comps = row.strip().split(',')
    for j in range(len(comps)):
        dataColumns[j].append(float(comps[j]))    

l = 0
for entry in dataColumns:
    mean = sum(dataColumns[l])/rowCount
    stdDevSum = 0
    for x in dataColumns:
        stdDevSum = float(stdDevSum) + (((float(comps[row]) - float(mean))** 2) for row in range(rowCount))
    stdDev = math.sqrt(stdDevSum / rowCount)
    print(l + 1, headers[l], max(dataColumns[l]), min(dataColumns[l]), "{0:0.2f}".format(mean), stdDev)
    l = l + 1

inputFile.close()
```

Edit:

Solution has been found

Comment: Please write a [mcve] and include the full error message and stack trace.

Comment: @kaya3 I have updated the code chunk. The error message has been explained in the question, including the full error message would be redundant.

Comment: *"... including the full error message would be redundant"* [Absolutely not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough).

Comment: @kaya3 As per your request, full error message has been copied and pasted.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: @AMC I have always used camelCasing, maybe it's because of my programming in other languages. Is this the standard in python?

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the reference for Python style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an error in this line:

```
    stdDev = math.sqrt((sum((float(comps[l]) - float(mean)) ** 2) in range(rowCount)) / rowCount)
```

The error comes specifically from the expression `sum((float(comps[l]) - float(mean))`. When you do `sum(something)`, Python tries to iterate over `something`. But in this case, the thing it's trying to iterate on is `float(comps[l]) - float(mean)`, which is just a number. Hence the error: `'float' object is not iterable`.

Also note that your use of `in range(rowCount)` is wrong. `a in b` means "return true if `a` is in `b`, return `false` otherwise". You were probably looking for the `for i in iterable` syntax.

### Solution

I'm assuming that you want the sum of `comps[row] - mean` for each row. Try this:

```
stdDev = math.sqrt(sum( (float(comps[row]) - float(mean)) **2 for row in range(rowCount) ) / rowCount)
```

Comment: Tried this. It makes sense, however, I am getting an error that says "IndexError: list index out of range". I assume it has to do with the comps[ ] list somehow.